# How to use shell operators like `&&` and `;` in C code

Tags: c, bash, x-dwm

I'm trying to make my status bar of DWM window manager to update whenever I change audio volume and keyboard layout. After searching the net, I found a way for keyboard switching:

```
static const char *kblayoutnext[]  = { "pkill", "-HUP", "dwm_bar.sh", NULL };
```

When I press the key to switch layout, using pkill and HUP signal the status bar is reloaded presenting the new setting.

For audio, this works for changing volume:

```
static const char *alsatoggle[]  = { "amixer", "-q", "set", "Master", "toggle", NULL };
```

but no refreshing on the status bar.

So I tried,

```
static const char *alsatoggle[]  = { "amixer", "-q", "set", "Master", "toggle", "&&", "pkill", "-HUP", "dwm_bar.sh", NULL };
```

and

```
static const char *alsatoggle[]  = { "amixer", "-q", "set", "Master", "toggle", ";", "pkill", "-HUP", "dwm_bar.sh", NULL };
```

but nothing happens; the alsa volume level does not change, and no refreshing of course. I suspect that the bash **&&** and **;** are not passed as they should inside C code.

Comment: Merely putting strings into an array has no effect on anything else. Presumably you are passing these arrays to some API that affects your terminal, window manager, shell, or other software. You need to show, state, or explain what you are doing with these arrays in that regard. From the looks of them, they may be used as arguments to something in the `exec` family of routines, which executes a single program. The `exec` routines do not parse commands as shells do.

Comment: To get shell features, instead of executing a command directly, you might instead execute `bash` with its `-c` switch to parse a command passed as a string.

Comment: Concerning your question, you are asking how to use feature X from programming language A in programming language B. That doesn't really make sense. Rather, think about what X does and then do a little research how to achieve something similar in B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same idea as Eric.  The issue with `;` and `&&` is that they are interpreted by the shell.  So, as Eric suggests,  run the shell.

Consider this:

```
static const char *alsatoggle[]  = { "sh", "-c" , "amixer -q set Master toggle && pkill -HUP dwm_bar.sh", NULL };
```

Comment: I also tried using an executable shell script. The alsatoggle.sh script is `amixer -q set Master toggle && pkill -HUP dwm_bar.sh` and the line inside C code: `static const char *alsatoggle[]  = { "alsatoggle.sh", NULL };`

Comment: It works, I don't know which is more efficient (executable script or sh -c)